# two digit decimal precision in javascript even if the user enters foo.nnn.nnbar

Tags: javascript, html

This seems like a nice general problem that has been asked and solved a million times. In fact, I am certain I had something that did the job years ago but long since lost it. The problem is simple, given a basic HTML ( or xhtml ) input element such as this :

```
<input name="some_num" type="text" id="some_num" 
       size="10" maxlength="10" value="0" 
       class="num_align_right" 
       title="decimal number with two digits right of the decimal point" >
```

Now in truth a user can enter "barfoo" or "aj2.34t" or maybe even "$2,345.67". What I really want is to extract the digits from whatever string is entered, one at a time, going left to right and taking note of the decimal point, if any.  If there are no decimal characters zero through nine ascii then the value is seen to be 0.00 in the field. Otherwise I am sure you get the idea.

So the first thing I did was come up with a way to detect a not-a-number and deal with it :

```
    function noNaN (a) {
        return (isNaN(a)) ? 0 : a;
    }
```

Simple and does what it does.

Then I tried a simple hack to get two digits of precision on whatever is in the field :

```
    function two_digit(amount) {
        amount -= 0;
        amount = ( Math.round(amount*100) )/100;
        return ( amount == Math.floor(amount)) ? amount + '.00' : ( (amount*10 == Math.floor(amount*10) ) ? amount + '0' : amount);
    }
```

Side comment .. I wish that were 72 chars wide but oh well.

In the input element I have the onfocus/onblur event :

```
onFocus="this.style.background='#ffff00';"
onblur="this.style.background='#e7caea'; var var1 = Math.abs(noNaN(parseFloat(this.value)));this.value=two_digit( var1 );"
```

Now when I click in the field I get a bright yellow background colour as well as the ability to enter a number which is right aligned. I enter 5.587 and then click anywhere else on the form and wonderfully the background colour changes to purple and the number becomes 5.59 in the field.

If I enter "5.874f52" in the field then I get "5.87" thanks to the onblur. Seems fine. However if I enter "aj44.34.1234" then I get "0.00" as a result as opposed to "44.34".

I know that it may seem unreasonable to try to protect oneself from the most moronic of users but if you could only see the users I am stuck with. So I gave serious thought to a simple piece of js that walks from left to right in the input string and extracts digits and decimal points only.  Therefore the input "aj44.34.1234" would become "44.34.1234" which works fine with what I have now and results in "44.34".  The input string "$2,345.67" is of course a clear NaN and falls to "0.00".

So I guess I am just looking for a way to do this without doing anything obscene.  Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Side Question : Are the js events in xhtml lowercase "onblur" and "onfocus" as opposed to the HTML spec which wants "onBlur" and "onFocus"?  Regardless of the fact that broswers seem to accept either.

--edit --- I forgot to add the input class css :

```
.inp_num_right
    {  
        font-family: Lucida Console,monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 1px;
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-style: 1px solid black;
        color: #000000;
    }
```

Comment: use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) it can set the fixed point notation.

Comment: that won't fix the problem if the input is "$2,345.67"

Comment: didnt say it would, just saying to get a 2 decimal place digit use toFixed, instead of your two_digit() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sanitize non-digit characters, you're best off using regular expressions to filter and remove unwanted characters. Here is a function I wrote for you that will do all the things you said you want to do with the input filter.

```
function sanitizeNumericInput(input) {

    // a negative sign comes before any digit
    var is_negative = /^[^0-9]*\-/.test(input)

    // remove anything that is not a digit or decimal point
    var digits = input.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

    // find the first decimal point
    var decimal_point = digits.indexOf('.');

    // no decimal point, don't worry about inserting one
    if(decimal_point == -1) decimal_point = digits.length;

    // remove all other decimal points and create a numeric string
    var clean = (is_negative?'-':'') + digits.substr(0, decimal_point) + '.' + digits.substr(decimal_point).replace(/\./g, '');

    // attempt to turn this into a number data-type
    var number = parseFloat(clean);

    // no digits (not a number) return '0.00'
    if(isNaN(number)) return '0.00';

    // round to two decimal places
    number = Math.round(number*100) / 100);

    // force two digits after the decimal point, convert to string and return it
    return number.toFixed(2)+'';
}
```

This handles non-numeric inputs, does rounding, negative numbers and forces two digits after the decimal place

```
sanitizeNumericInput('az-12charlie8.234567'); // -128.23
sanitizeNumericInput('no numbers'); // 0.00
sanitizeNumericInput('0'); // 0.00
sanitizeNumericInput('123'); // 123.00
sanitizeNumericInput('-123.4'); // -123.40
sanitizeNumericInput('12.459'); // 12.46
```

Also, I recommend you avoid using `onblur` and `onfocus` attributes to run javascript. Look into using DOM event bindings, you can do it very easily with jQuery like so:

```
$('#some_num').bind('change', function(){
    this.value = sanitizeNumericInput(this.value);
});
```

Comment: That Sir looks like a slick piece of code that is perfect. I will give that a try. One comment, I can not use jQuery at all. In fact, I have to stick with basic js only and xhtml 1.0 strict DTD as a enforced spec by people that wear a belt with suspenders.

Comment: Am trying to use that with var f1 = document.getElementById('some_num');  followed by var var1 = sanitizeNumericInput(f1.value);  and alert ( var1 ); which never happens. I literally see nothing. argghh ... js fun.

Comment: `document.getElementById('some_num').addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.value = sanitizeNumericInput(this.value);
}, false);`

Comment: I don't know what this "addEventListener" is. It is not listed anywhere on this page http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp or in the xhtml spec.

Comment: oh .. I see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FEventTarget.addEventListener